# What are the best wwdc videos to watch regarding performance optimization?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, wwdc

There are are plenty of videos in Apple WWDC page touching on various topics regarding iOS, Mac OSX, Safari etc.

I've seen some Apple WWDC videos, but I want them in categories; like all In-App Purchase videos in a particular section etc.

Is there any way I can find a list of the videos for Performance Optimization in iOS only
as right now that's what I feel the most important part of iOS development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no specific way to find **only** performance optimisation videos.  You might as well just pick-and-choose the videos you want from the 2011 and 2012 WWDC videos.

For performance optimisation on iOS, I would recommend the following videos from the 2012 WWDC (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/):

- Session 225 - Up and Running: Making a Great Impression with Every Launch
- Session 235 - iOS App Performance: Responsiveness
- Session 238 - iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations
- Session 242 - iOS App Performance: Memory

And two rather specific videos which fall under optimising the user experience:

- Session 240 - Polishing Your Interface Rotations
- Session 208 - Saving and Restoring Application State on iOS